# how to to display the category user created by the current user on every page

Tags: python, django

as title indicates I'm trying to send the name of a category user created by the current user on every page. My initial attempt was simply

```
{% if user.is_authenticated == category.author %}
  {{category.name}}
 {% endif %}
```

but this only displays the category in a certain page, while I want to display this in the navbar which I have it included for the every page. So I thought I should do `category = models.foreignkey('category')` in my user model but got told I should set a queryset in a template context processor. which I'm not sure it's the best way to do. 
Can someone please direct me how I should do such matter?

here's my code

```
class Category(models.Model): 
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        description = models.TextField()
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

and in my views.py

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser and Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
        return render(request,'main/category_already_exists.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('category', category_name_url=category.name)

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()
    context = {
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html',context)
```

and this is my simplified category view

```
def category(request, category_name_url):
    category_name = decode_url(category_name_url)


                category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)

    context = {

                "category":category,



        }
    return render(request, "main/category.html", context)
```

and this is my model for my user 
    from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name='my_profile')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this information in `request.session`. You can do this like this:

Suppose your login view is this:

```
def login(request):
    # Do login stuff
    if user.is_active():
        request.session['categories'] = [ c.name for c in Category.objects.filter(author=request.user)] # add to the session 
    return redirect('/somepage')
```

Display this data in every page like this:

```
{% for c in request.session.categories %}
{{ c }}
{% endfor %}
```

And update the category list every time the a new category is added like this:

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser and Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
        return render(request,'main/category_already_exists.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            request.session['categories'] = [ c.name for c in Category.objects.filter(author=request.user)]
            return redirect('category', category_name_url=category.name)

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()
    context = {
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html',context)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should write your own context processor and include it in settings. Link to docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#context-processors

Definition from Django docs:

"Context processors are functions that receive the current HttpRequest as an argument and return a dict of data to be added to the rendering context.

Their main use is to add common data shared by all templates to the context without repeating code in every view."

Comment: thanks but I don't know how I can do that which is why I posted here

Comment: Step 1. Create a file context_processors.py
Step 2. Add a function to it and call it get_category(request)
Step 3. Make your get_category function return a dictionary with your category in it.
Step 4. Include the full path to the get_category inside your settings file in the same format the default context processors are included. 

Take a look at default Django context processors. They're all simple functions that except request and return a dick https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/context_processors.py

Comment: hmm I already got what I wanted with the other solution here, but I'll try this as well